# Función para hallar un porcentaje en un diccionario

Tags: python, diccionarios, porcentaje

estaba realizando un proyecto yo al inicio solo puse el departamento y el porcentaje pero me pedían que realice todo desde python.
pero me dijeron que luego tendría que agregarle archivos así que no sería eficiente.

[image: según este cuadro debo sacar el po]

debo sacar el porcentaje de los que sí tiene agua, en el diccionario solo debe ir el valor de los que tienen agua y mediante una función sacar el porcentaje. Yo lo hice así:

```
 d1_4 = {"AMAZONAS": str((round(74505 * 100 / 107364, 2))), "ANCASH": str((round(249678 * 100 / 313661, 2))),
            "APURÍMAC": str((round(89757 * 100 / 126048, 2))), "AREQUIPA": str((round(388404 * 100 / 425522, 2)))}
```

pero si uso la función archivos no será eficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo este diccionario de ejemplo:

```py
data = {
    "concepto1": {
        "a": 14,
        "b": 34
    },
    "concepto2": {
        "a": 4,
        "b": 535
    },
    "concepto3": {
        "a": 8,
        "b": 54
    }
}
```

Una forma de calcular cada porcentaje de "**a**" respecto a "**b**" es la siguiente:

```py
for v in data.values():
    v["porcentaje"] = round((v["a"] / v["b"]) * 100, 2)
```

Con esto, iteramos sobre cada valor de `data`. Cada valor (`v`) es un diccionario (por ejemplo: `{"a": 14, "b": 34}`) y añadimos a él una nueva clave llamada "**porcentaje**".

`data` queda así:

```
{'concepto1': {'a': 14, 'b': 34, 'porcentaje': 41.18},
 'concepto2': {'a': 4, 'b': 535, 'porcentaje': 0.75},
 'concepto3': {'a': 8, 'b': 54, 'porcentaje': 14.81}}
```

Podrías hacer algo parecido con tu diccionario.